# Blood relation problem - how is G related to S?

Tags: logical-deduction, family

> A is the son of P and brother in law of T, who is the sister of G. B is the husband of K. K has only two children, T is one of them. S is the mother of A and sister of W who is the husband of R. U is the brother of P.

If V is the brother of A, then who is the aunt of V? It would be great if someone helps me to figure this out with the help of a family tree. It would be much easier for me to interpret.

One more follow up question to this is, how is G related to S?

Comment: "brother-in-law" may refer to two possible relations, and the rest of the clues don't disambiguate which. [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2040/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked out this family tree based on the given information. It uses standard notation. I assumed that only male-female marriages occurred because (based on chat history) this seems to be the kind of test which would assume that.

> [image: family tree]

Based on this tree,

> R

is V's only aunt, and G is S's

> daughter-in-law. (Equivalently, S is G's mother-in-law)

Answer (score 5):

There is some ambiguity here but I would say the answer is

> R

Focus on this line

> "S is the mother of A and sister of W".
>  We subsequently discover that W is male so is the uncle of A, hence his wife (R) is the aunt of A and also V since they are siblings.

What is assumed

> R is female - of course R could be male and thus be another uncle in which case the aunt remains unknown from the information given.

Answer (score 3):

> V is the brother of A. S is the mother of A and sister of W, who is the husband of R, so R is aunt of V.

Comment: How is G related to S? Can you help me in this by drawing a family tree?

Comment: I figured upto T as the daughter in law. Ok? But G is the sister of T. So how do I relate now?

Comment: How daughter in law? T is daughter in law right. G's gender is even not known. How do we conclude. Also she is the brother/sister of daughter in law. Yes or no?